# winform designs for lots of categories and information

Tags: c#, winforms

This will be a question more for the application designers out there, but ALL answers are welcome, so get ready!

I am about to develop an application that will house a lot of different user controls, information, views, categories, etc..

I have been thinking and doing research but I am not sure on what to research so maybe you guys can help me out. I need a design type for my windows form that will allow a lot of information to be shown as well as categorized. For example, imagine categoires like the ones shown on the end of this post.

I need to be able to have the user find their way around all of that in a not so confusing way. I was thinking of some sort of tab system or possibly using a windows ribbon but I just feel that will over complicate things and make everything look to busy. I also have blend, so WPF is an option.

If you have any ideas, links, pictures, or better yet examples please answer this. I am more of a programmer than a designer, so as long as I have something to design I can do it. Thank you in advance, I look forward to seeing the design types you show.

(Below is a shorted example of the categories)

```
A
-> aa
   -> aaa
      -> aaaa
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> aaab
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> aaac
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
   -> aab
      -> aaaa
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> aaab
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> aaac
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
-> ab
   -> aba
      -> abaa
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> abab
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> abac
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
   -> abb
      -> abaa
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> abab
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> abac
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
```

(this is now a second main category, there will be as many as 5 of these)

```
B
-> ba
   -> baa
      -> baaa
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> baab
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> baac
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
   -> bab
      -> baaa
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> baab
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> baac
         -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
    -> bb
       -> bba
          -> bbaa
             -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
           -> bbab
             -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
           -> bbac
             -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
       -> bbb
          -> bbaa
             -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
           -> bbab
             -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
           -> bbac
             -> Here lies the user control that will be loaded
```

There will most likely be 6 main categories, which each having multiple sub categories. Each category will be a button or a link that goes deeper until a "aaaa" deep button is clicked and the usercontrol is loaded.

To help further explain what might happen is.

A is clicked. Now you see AA, AB, AC, etc.,. You click AA and you see AAA,AAC,AAAB,etc.,. When that is clicked a user control is loaded.

Thank you for those few that read this entire thing, I wanted to give as much data as possible so this is not closed for being general or something.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question...

Comment: You need to describe the usage scenario a little bit better. Would the user use only one of the leaf user controls at a time? Will they switch user control often? What's the size of the controls, do they fit on screen all at once (like cells in an Excel sheet) or are they large? Will the user use more time finding the right control or most time working in the user control? Do the user controls work independently or are they linked in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with a 2010 ribbon with a tree list as the content if needed.